# Output All Paths in a Zip file in ruby

Tags: ruby, path, zip, glob

I am trying to **check a zip file** *for file paths that exceed a specified character limit*. I was able to do this easily with a regular folder path using:

```
Dir.glob("#{root_path}/*")
```

And then iterating through the paths given from the glob and comparing their lengths to my given character limit. Is there a way to do this with a zip file without actually unzipping it?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you have no choice but to unzip the file

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the zip class and it has an entries property. So if you open the zip in with the zip library you can access all the file path names by iterating through each “entry” and accessing each entry’s “name” property which is a string of the path.

For example:

```
require 'zip'

paths = Array.new
zip = Zip::File.open(my_zip, false)
zip.entries.each do |entry|
  paths << entry.name
end
```

Returning the paths array will give you an array of each path in the zip file as a string.